# Sum of series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log {x})^{\log{n}}}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, parametric

I need to find the sum of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log {x})^{\log{n}}}, x \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm pretty sure this can be solved using a comparison test but I fail to see how this could be done.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I did a cauchy's convergence test and it looks like the series may converge absolutely for $x \lt -e \lor x \gt e$

Comment: For $x<-e$, the series isn't defined, so it doesn't converge.

Comment: what's the point of having $\log x$ in there instead of $x$?

Comment: @thedude That's the exercise's text.

Comment: @NTAuthority That may be. But you should exercise your own common sense

Comment: @thedude I think I do exercise my own common sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that 
$$ x^{\log n}=e^{\log x \log n}=n^{\log x}$$

we see that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{\log n}}$ converges as long as $\log x>1$

In your case this would be $\log (\log x)>1$.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get to the same result by using cauchy's condensation test. Yet, my book gives me a different result.

Comment: Which result does it give?

Comment: $x \gt e^{\frac{2}{\log{2}}}$

Comment: Looks like it comes from using a different basis for the logarithm

Comment: Edit: the result it gives is $x \gt e^{2^{\frac{1}{log{2}}}}$. It looks like it comes out from an absolute convergence check. I just don't understand how (it's the same log base by the way).

Comment: @NTAuthority $2^{\frac{1}{\log{2}}}=e^{\frac{\log{2}}{\log{2}}}=e$

Comment: @ProfessorVector Right, didn't see that at first. Thanks a lot! I wish I could upvote but I'm unable to.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, $(\log x)^{\log n}=e^{\log \log x\,\log n}=n^{\log \log x}$, so the series converges for $x>e^e$, and its value is $\zeta(\log \log x)$.