# Test the convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $a>0$, test the convergence of the infinite series: $$\sum a^{\ln(n)}$$ Which test should be better to use here? I tried the D'Alembert's ratio test. $$\lim_{n\to \infty} {\frac{a^{\ln(n)}}{a^{\ln(n+1)}}}= \lim_{n\to \infty}a^{ln{\frac{n}{n+1}}}=a^0=1$$ So the test failed.

**UPDATE:** I observed that $${a^{\ln(n)}}=e^{{\ln(a)}{\ln(n)}}={n^{\ln(a)}}={{1\over n^{ln({1\over a})}} }$$Further by test of auxiliary series $$\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$$ we know that criterion for convergence is $p>1$.
Here $p=ln({1\over a})$.Hence the series will be convergent when $ln(a)<-1$ i.e. when $0<a<1/e$, since $a>0$ is already given.Finally this solved my question.

Comment: Which ones did you try already? Which ones do you know? What were the results? We aren't here to do your homework, you know.

Comment: That's essentially the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518182/sum-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-log-x-logn-x-in-math/2518223#2518223)

Comment: this converges if $$\log(|a|)+1<0$$ is hold.

Comment: @5xum I tried the D Alembert ratio test but it failed.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sir that is the right answer, kindly suggest how should i proceed as i don't know many tests.

Comment: Make yourself familiar with [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test) and the other ones on that page. But here, note that $a^{\ln n} = \exp\bigl((\ln n)(\ln a)\bigr) = n^{\ln a}$.

Comment: Sir I solved the question with what I knew, as I am unaware of the higher tests that could solve this quicker, if any. I am still learning this chapter in my institute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if wrong.

$a_n=a^{\ln(n)}; $

Rewrite: $a =e^k$, then $k=\ln(a).$

$a_n = [e^k]^{\ln(n)} =e^{k\ln(n)}$

$a_n= n^k$, where $k= \ln(a) \in \mathbb{R}.$

$\sum a^{\ln(n)}:$

1) $-1 \le k$,  divergent.

4) $k\lt -1$, convergent.

Comment: Yes that is right. I used the same approach. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: Shatabdi. Thanks for your comment.We are on the same track.:))))